# Changing CSS in Gmail's iframe content with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, gmail

Trying to change the nav bar in Gmail to a different color. What I have below is not picking up the **canvas_frame** even though I can see it when I view the source?

What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("#canvas_frame").length) {
  $("#canvas_frame").load(function() {
     $("#canvas_frame").contents().find(".qp").css("background-color","#FF0000");
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: What is the context of this code snippet? Is this a greasemonkey script?

Comment: Yes, this is for a greasemonkey script. I'm using the `@require` to load the latest jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

How are you running your Javascript code? I can change the colour by following these steps -

- Open Firefox (with Firebug installed)
- Install jquerify bookmarklet (http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/04/better-stronger-safer-jquerify-bookmarklet)
- Go to GMail and run the bookmarklet

If I then run the following code in the Firebug console window the colour changes -

```
jQuery("#canvas_frame").contents().find(".qp").css("background-color","#00ff00");
```

Comment: Your instruction works, but that's when everything on the page is already loaded. I think what I need help with now is getting the the script to detect when the iFrame has loaded completely. And I don't think `$("#canvas_frame").load(function(){});` is working with Gmail.

Comment: Can't you use $(document).load instead of .ready? Otherwise you could use polling to check if the frame has loaded en .qp exists. Alternatively you could use userContent.css if using firefox.